# Is there any struts2 jquery progressive file upload plugin?

Tags: jquery-plugins, file-upload, struts2

Is there any file upload plugin (tag library support) with a good progress bar like jQuery, that would work on Struts2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you know the [struts2 fileupload plugin](http://code.google.com/p/ajax-file-upload-struts2/)? This is based on jQuery.

Maybe you can also try it with the  tag from the [Struts2 jQuery Plugin](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/) in combination with an [Execute and Wait Interceptor](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/execute-and-wait-interceptor.html) from Struts2. But i did not try it. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so sure the fact that you are using Struts will really affect the client-side plugin to show a progress bar, but have you taken a look at [uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) yet?