# File upload Progress bar in struts2?

Tags: java, struts2

I want to implement file upload progress monitor bar over file upload functionality of struts 2... ?

Comment: try this one http://code.google.com/p/ajax-file-upload-struts2/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6579171/is-there-any-struts2-jquery-prograssive-file-upload-plugin

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to use [ajax-file-upload-struts2](http://code.google.com/p/ajax-file-upload-struts2/) which is Ajax based but not so active in development.

Other option is to use plain JQuery code with [execute-and-wait-interceptor](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/execute-and-wait-interceptor.html).The ExecuteAndWaitInterceptor is great for running long-lived actions in the background while showing the user a nice progress meter, So when the upload is in progress you can keep showing some kind of progress animation to user.You can also play around with [S2-JQuery plugin](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/) also.

Comment: I tried using execute and wait interceptor..... I am facing two problems 1) I get to page i define in result type wait.. but never redirect to sucess page... 2) how can I show that progress bar part on the jsp page ??????

Comment: @dhroove: for the progress bar follow this example, though not very good but will give you some ides http://www.roseindia.net/struts/struts/struts2.2.1/exeAndWait_Interceptor.html and will try to find some time to create some example over weekend :). regarding redirection you can redirect using some JS code once the upload done completely

Comment: @AtulD: Have you looked in to `S2-JQuery plugin`, file upload is being provided by plugin out of the box.

Comment: I saw the code , but dont have idea how to make it run can you provide help

Comment: `@Umesh` How can I show progress bar on Same jsp page ?????? On which i am going to upload file .